# Can you explain what HTTP `referer' is and its example?

Tags: http, http-referer

Can you explain what  HTTP `referer' is?

I wrote my answer down. please comment to this.

Comment: If you want to create a self-answered question, put the answer as an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

My answer is here.

The referer is the URL from which came a request received by a server.

Please comment to this.

Example)

I want to access to the Harvard University website to get Master degree. I do not know the website address. so, I google Harvard University, and successfully access to the website. in this case, Google is the HTTP 'referer'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP `Referer` is a request header that contains the address of the previous web page (on a different domain) from which a link to the current web page or resource was requested.

e.g. you searched "youtube" in google and from the result you clicked a link (& your url is "https://google.com?key=value") and youtube website opens up.

in the process when you clicked the link, (a porton of) your url will be set to the `Referer` header and then sent to youtube server (then youtube server sends you a web page that is shown in that tab)

you can view it from the network setting in chromes console. ex:

[image: referrer header]